# Most efficient way to remove objects from array based on key value objects in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Given the excludes and items arrays, I want to return an array of objects from items that don't contain a key, value pair corresponding to a key, value pair object in excludes. Is there a better way of solving this other than using nested for loops?

```
const excludes = [{key: "color", value: "Red"}, {key: "age", value:12}, {key:"score", value: 75}];

const items = [{color: "Red", score: 30, age: 12}, {color: "Blue", score: 100, age: 20}, {color: "Red", score: 75, age: 30}];

//Expected output: [{color: "Blue", score: 100, age: 20}]
```

Comment: Use the `filter()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), as suggested by @Barmar, in combination with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) as follows:

```js
const excludes = [{key: "color", value: "Red"}, {key: "age", value:12}, {key:"score", value: 75}],
      items = [{color: "Red", score: 30, age: 12}, {color: "Blue", score: 100, age: 20}, {color: "Red", score: 75, age: 30}],
      
      output = items.filter(
          item => excludes.every(
              ({key,value}) => item[key] !== value
          )
      );

console.log( output );
//OUTPUT: [{color: "Blue", score: 100, age: 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` to filter the `items` array. The filtering criteria checks each of the properties of the item against the `excludes` array. If none of them match, the item is included in the result.

```js
const excludes = [{key: "color", value: "Red"}, {key: "age", value:12}, {key:"score", value: 75}];

const items = [{color: "Red", score: 30, age: 12}, {color: "Blue", score: 100, age: 20}, {color: "Red", score: 75, age: 30}];

let result = items.filter(item =>
  !Object.entries(item).some(([key, value]) => 
    excludes.find(e => e.key = key && e.value == value)));
console.log(result);
```